# document.title in React (static pages)

Tags: reactjs

I have two 'static' pages in React: "About", and "Terms and Conditions". They don't have any state nor props.

What is the best way to render `document.title` when these pages are shown?

I'm using functional stateless component so there is no `componentDidMount`.

```
export default function About() {
  return (<article>
          <h1>About us</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          </div>
          </article>);
}
```

On one website it was suggested to use `document.title = "About"` before return statement as shown below. As functional components can be considered to have implicit `render()` and `render()` should be a pure function (it doesn't interact with browser) than that's not optimal solution.

```
export default function About() {
  document.title = "About";
  return (<article>
          <h1>About us</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          </div>
          </article>);
}
```

Does it make sense to use another class component `<WindowTitle title="About" />` which uses `componentDidMount` to modify window title, and use that component inside functional component? Or there is better solution?

```
class WindowTitle extends Component() {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = this.props.title;
    }
}

function About() {
  return (<article>
          <WindowTitle title="About" />
            <h1>About us</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
          </div>
          </article>);
}
```

Comment: use `react-helmet`

Comment: What is best option to change document.title without using additional modules? I'm learning React so I'm curious what is best way to solve it using plain React.

Comment: "plain react" doesn't care much about external environment (browser, document) - don't search purity in this case

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to add tags in the head of the html is using [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) package. It will also allow to add other head tags.

```
<Helmet>
   <meta charSet="utf-8" />
   <title>My Title</title>
   <link rel="canonical" href="" />
</Helmet>
```